# Are big O and little O closed?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

If $f_n(x)=O(g(x))$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$, then is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=O(g(x))$? In other words, is Big O notation closed?

What about little O notation? If $f_n(x)=o(g(x))$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$, then is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=o(g(x))$?

Comment: It is an interesting question but in order to have a limit you have to have some sort of distance function.  I'd suggest that you add a more formal definition of what the limit of a sequence of function means in the context of this question in order to get a good answer.

Comment: If you mean pointwise limit, the answer to your question is no: for big O, take $g(x) = x$, and $f_n(x) = nx$. For little o, take $g(x) = x$, $f_n(x) = n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, in the case your constant depends on $n$, then as @Rylee mentioned, you can have $f_n(x)=nx$, $g(x)=x$and in this case $|\lim f_n(x)|=\infty$ (for $x\neq 0$) so, you can't have $\lim f_n(x)=O(g(x))$.

But if your constant is uniform (independent from $n$) for instance $|f_n(x)|\leq 2|g(x)|$, then certainly passing to the limit, you will have $|\limsup f_n(x)|\leq 2|g(x)|$, i.e. $\limsup f_n(x)=O(g(x))$